# How to get the formula from its recurrence relation $A(n,m)=A(n-1,m)+A(n-1,m-1)+A(n-2,m)-A(n-2,m-1)$ or its generating function?

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

1. The recurrence relation of $A(n,m)$:
   $$A(n,m)=A(n-1,m)+A(n-1,m-1)+A(n-2,m)-A(n-2,m-1) \quad\text{for} \quad n\ge2, A(0,0)=0, A(1,0)=1.$$
2. The generating function $F_n(z)$:
   $$F_n(z)=\sum_{m}A(n,m)z^m$$
   and form its recurrence relation, we can get
   $$F_n(z)=(1+z)F_{n-1}(z)+(1-z)F_{n-2}(z),\quad\text{for} \quad n\ge3,F_1(z)=1, F_2(z)=(1+z).$$

QUESTION: In the paper, they get $A(n,m)=\sum_k\binom{k}{m}\binom{n-1-k}{k-m}$ and said it is routine to verify. How can we get the formula of $A(n,m)$ from its recurrence relation or  generating function? By hand or with a computer program?

I have calculated for a long time to get $A(n,m)$ but failed.
Here is the way I tried. By using Mathematica，
$$F_n(z)=-\frac{2^{-n} \left(\left(-\sqrt{z^2-2 z+5}+z+1\right)^n-\left(\sqrt{z^2-2 z+5}+z+1\right)^n\right)}{\sqrt{z^2-2 z+5}}.$$ By doing this way, $A(n,m)$ is the coefficient of $z^m$ of $$2^{-n+1} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(1+z)^{n-2k-1}(5-2 z+z^2)^k.$$
Then
$$A(n,m)=\\
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } 2^{1-n} (-2)^{i+2 j-m} 5^{k-j}\binom{k}{j} \binom{n}{2 k+1}  \binom{j}{i+2 j-m} \binom{-2 k+n-1}{i},$$
It's really hard for me to get $F_n(z)$'s coefficients of $z^m$ from its expression and the result I got is pretty different from the result above.

Comment: "$A(n, m)$ is the coefficient of $x^m$ of [something in which the symbol $x$ does not appear]"

Comment: Have you tried using a two-variable generating function $\sum_{m, n} A(n, m) x^n y^m$?  Did that yield anything?

Comment: That was a slip of the pen and I have changed x to z. Thanks for pointing out the error. Besides, I didn't try using the two-variable generating function, I will have a try, thanks for your advice.

Comment: Ok let me know how it goes :)

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I was ill and haven't checked this for quite a long time... It seems like the expression got from the two-variable one is quiet similar to what we want，$$F(n,m)=x/(1-(x+xy+x^2-x^2y)$$, thus $$A(n,m)=\sum _{i=0}^{\infty } \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \binom{i}{m} \binom{m}{k} (-1)^k \binom{i-m}{n-1-i-k}$$, but I still failed.

Comment: I agree with your GF, but the coefficient extraction does not seem right (?).  (And certainly no apology necessary!)

Comment: $$F(x,y)=x/1-(x+x^2+xy-x^2y)=x\sum_i {(x+x^2+xy-x^2y)^i}=x\sum_i \sum_m {\binom{i}{m}(x+x^2)^{i-m}(x-x^2)^my^m}=x^{k+1}\sum_m\sum_k \binom{i}{m}(1+x)^{k-m}(1-x)^my^m$$, then we will get $A(n,m)$ like that above. There may have the identity $$\sum_k \binom{m}{k}(-1)^k\binom{i-m}{n-1-i-k}=\binom{n-i-1}{i-m}$$.

Comment: Well what you've written in this last comment is definitely not right in several ways; in particular the last equation is surely false (try $m = i = 1$, $n = 3$ for example).  On the other hand the "(?)" in my previous comment may have been merited (maybe I had my $m$, $n$ reversed relative to yours, or something), as I agree that a corrected version of the derivation in your last comment yields that formula.

Comment: I have checked for many times for the expression $A(n,m)$ and didn't find any error, $$A(n,m)=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \sum _{i=0}^{\infty } \binom{k}{m} \binom{m}{i} (-1)^i \binom{k-m}{n-1-i-k}$$, which was derived in the way above. And you're  right, the identity in my last comment is wrong, but I did get the expression $A(n,m)$ like this and the identity should hold if I calculated $A(n,m)$ correctly(?).

Comment: Yes, I agree.  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have (correctly) computed the generating function $F(x, y) = \frac{x}{1 - x - x^2 - xy + x^2y}$.  There are many possible procedures to extract a formula for a coefficient in this series; if you want to end up specifically with the one you quoted, then you can rewrite this as
\begin{align*} 
F(x, y) &= \frac{x}{1 - x} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - \frac{x}{1 - x}(x + y - xy)} \\
& = \frac{x}{1 - x} \sum_k  \frac{x^k}{(1 - x)^k}(x + y - xy)^k \\
& = \sum_k (1 - x)^{-k - 1} x^{2k + 1} \left(1 + \frac{y(1 - x)}{x}\right)^k \\
& = \sum_k (1 - x)^{-k - 1} x^{2k + 1} \sum_m \binom{k}{m} \left(\frac{y(1 - x)}{x}\right)^m \\
& = \sum_m y^m \sum_k \binom{k}{m} (1 - x)^{m - k - 1} x^{2k + 1 - m} \\
& = \sum_m y^m \sum_k \binom{k}{m} \sum_N \binom{N+ k - m}{k - m} x^{N + 2k + 1 - m} \\
& = \sum_m y^m \sum_k \binom{k}{m} \sum_n \binom{(n - 2k - 1 + m) + k - m}{k - m} x^{n} \\
& = \sum_m\sum_n x^n y^m \sum_k \binom{k}{m} \binom{n - k - 1 }{k - m}.
\end{align*}

(Did I really derive this this way?  No, of course I started at the other end and then wrote it upside down.  Other paths are undoubtedly possible, and the answer can undoubtedly be written in a plethora of other forms.)

Answer (score 0):

... I have calculated for a long time to get $A(n,m)$ but failed. Here is the way I tried. By using Mathematica...

We can solve easily this recurrence by reducing it to a two dimensional equivalent first order recurrence

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 f^1_n \\
 f^2_n \\
\end{array}
\right)
= 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 1-z & z+1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 f^1_{n-1} \\
 f^2_{n-1} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

so determining the eigenvalues we have

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 1-z & z+1 \\
\end{array}
\right) = 
T\Lambda T^{-1}=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{z+\sqrt{(z-2) z+5}+1}{2 (z-1)} & \frac{z-\sqrt{(z-2) z+5}+1}{2 (z-1)} \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{z^2-2 z+5}+z+1\right) & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{z^2-2 z+5}+z+1\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{z+\sqrt{(z-2) z+5}+1}{2 (z-1)} & \frac{z-\sqrt{(z-2) z+5}+1}{2 (z-1)} \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)^{-1}
$$

so the difference now reads

$$
T^{-1}\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 f^1_n \\
 f^2_n \\
\end{array}
\right) = \Lambda T^{-1}\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 f^1_{n-1} \\
 f^2_{n-1} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

etc.